# Using tab as a delimiter in orange's basket format

Tags: python, orange

[Orange's basket format](http://orange.biolab.si/docs/latest/reference/rst/Orange.data.formats/#basket-format) dictates various items in a single transaction (line) to be delimited by a comma. However, I am using tuples as a single item, hence comma as a delimiter is not an option for me. Does anybody know how to read `Orange.data.Table` from a `.basket` file using `tab` as a delimiter?

Comment: Perhaps you can still use comma if you check out the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648537/how-to-split-a-string-by-commas-positioned-outside-of-parenthesis)?

Comment: I can, but Orange won't. It wants file in which items in a transaction are separated by commas.