# How would I write the java regular expression for the following pattern

Tags: java, regex

How would I write the java regular expression for the following pattern:

```
"123(1,2),234(1,2),345(1,2),123456(1,2),789(1,2)";
```

The result should print out like this:

```
123
(1,2)
234
(1,2)
345
(1,2)
123456
(1,2)
789
(1,2)
```

Comment: You may find [this Java regex text website](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) helpful.

Comment: Regex cost a lot of brain power. I would like to write a for loop and finish it off.

Comment: `String[] output = input.replace("("," (").replace("),", ") ").split(" ");`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to split a string by commas positioned outside of parenthesis?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648537/how-to-split-a-string-by-commas-positioned-outside-of-parenthesis)

Comment: @Enigmadan Not quite. That question was about splitting on the comma after the parentheses but not any commas inside them, whereas this one is about separately capturing the parentheses and their contents, and the sequences of numbers outside of the parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Do a global match with this regex: `(?<=^|\),)[0-9]+|\([0-9]+,[0-9]+\)`. That matches either a group of consecutive digits preceded by ")," or the beginning of the string, or a sequence in the format **(#,#)** where **#** is a group of consecutive digits.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
String[] parts = str.split("(?=\\()|(?<=\\)),");
```

Here's a test:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    String str = "123(1,2),234(1,2),345(1,2),123456(1,2),789(1,2)";
    String[] parts = str.split("(?=\\()|(?<=\\)),");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts)); }
}
```

Output:

```
[123, (1,2), 234, (1,2), 345, (1,2), 123456, (1,2), 789, (1,2)]
```