# Spliting the character into parts

Tags: r, gsub, substr, grepl

I observe the following character:

```
  l <- "mod, range1 = seq(-m, n, 0.1), range2 = seq(-2, 2, 0.1), range3 = seq(-2, 2, 0.1)"
```

Using regular expressions in R I desire to split `l` in the following structure:

```
[1] "mod"                      "range1 = seq(-m, n, 0.1)"
[3] "range2 = seq(-2, 2, 0.1)" "range3 = seq(-2, 2, 0.1)"
```

Unfortunetely, I didn't find a proper way to overcome the problem, yet. Anyone has an idea how is it possible to acquire such an elegeant split?

Comment: I wonder why you are trying to split up R code stored in a character vector. On the face of it, as commenters below have said, regexes may not be powerful enough to do what you want. Can you provide some context for the problem?

Comment: Go back and tell the originator not to write such foolish constructions. Make him put each alleged command on a separate line, e.g.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I really doubt you can do it with regular expression. You are trying to *parse* your string and so you need a parser, which is generally more powerful than a regex. I don't think it's general enough, but you can take advantage of the R parser and the `alist` class. Try:

```
res<-eval(parse(text=paste0("alist(",l,")")))
paste0(names(res),ifelse(names(res)!="","=",""),as.character(res))
#[1] "mod"                    "range1=seq(-m, n, 0.1)" "range2=seq(-2, 2, 0.1)"
#[4] "range3=seq(-2, 2, 0.1)"
```

Keep in mind that the regex proposed solutions fail if there are nested brackets. Try them and mine with:

```
l<-"mod, range1 = seq(-m, n, 0.1), range2 = seq(-2, exp(2), 0.1), range3 = seq(-2, 2, 0.1)"
```

to understand what I mean.

Comment: Obligatory `fortune(106)`  .  Not that I think you have much choice in this case :-( .  I was tempted to recursively run `do.call( l[1:j])`, report when success happens, trim `l` appropriately & repeat, but that's about as ugly as code could get :-) .   Just out of interest, **is** there an `R` function or package that can check for syntactically valid strings?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft guess you can use `parse` and if no error is produced, the string is valid.

Answer (score 4):

Based on [this regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648537/how-to-split-a-string-by-commas-positioned-outside-of-parenthesis), you can use `str_extract_all` from `stringr`,

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(l, '(?:[^,(]|\\([^)]*\\))+')
#[[1]]
#[1] "mod" " range1 = seq(-m, n, 0.1)" " range2 = seq(-2, 2, 0.1)" " range3 = seq(-2, 2, 0.1)"
```

or

```
trimws(unlist(str_extract_all(l, '(?:[^,(]|\\([^)]*\\))+')))
#[1] "mod" "range1 = seq(-m, n, 0.1)" "range2 = seq(-2, 2, 0.1)" "range3 = seq(-2, 2, 0.1)"
```

Comment: May have same problems than @akrun's solution.

Comment: @nicola, indeed, this will fail with nested brackets.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a `base R` option based on the `pattern` showed in the OP's post.  Here we match all the characters starting from `(` to the `)`, skip it and split by `,` followed by space.

```
strsplit(l, "\\([^)]+\\)(*SKIP)(*F)|, ", perl = TRUE)[[1]]
#[1] "mod"                      "range1 = seq(-m, n, 0.1)"
#[3] "range2 = seq(-2, 2, 0.1)" "range3 = seq(-2, 2, 0.1)"
```

#### Update

Using @nicola's 'l'

```
strsplit(l, ", (?=[[:alnum:]]+\\s+\\=)", perl = TRUE)[[1]]
#[1] "mod"                           "range1 = seq(-m, n, 0.1)"   
#[3]  "range2 = seq(-2, exp(2), 0.1)" "range3 = seq(-2, 2, 0.1)"
```

and the previous 'l'

```
strsplit(l, ", (?=[[:alnum:]]+\\s+\\=)", perl = TRUE)[[1]]
#[1] "mod"                      "range1 = seq(-m, n, 0.1)" 
#[3] "range2 = seq(-2, 2, 0.1)" "range3 = seq(-2, 2, 0.1)"
```

Comment: Could you please explain the part of `split = "\\([^)]+\\)(*SKIP)(*F)|, "`. It would be very helpful.

Comment: Nice regex, but don't think it's general enough. Try with nested `()`. Check my answer to see it.

Comment: @nicola You are right.  But, my regex was based on the OP's pattern.

Comment: I guess that a formal language theorist could actually show that no regex could solve this problem (or maybe I'm saying something false, I'm not an expert of the field at all...).