# Split string according to commas in R

Tags: r, text, strsplit

I have the following:

```
s <- "abc, xyz, poi (cv, r2, 44, rghj), wer"
```

How can I split it so the end result is:

```
c("abc", "xyz", "poi (cv, r2, 44, rghj)", "wer")
```

Basically, `strsplit` the string at every comma, but outside the parentheses.

Comment: See a similar post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37811450/spliting-the-character-into-parts); modifying nicola's post a bit: `sapply(eval(parse(text = paste("alist(", s, ")", sep = ""))), deparse)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
strsplit(s, "\\([^)]+\\)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|, ", perl = TRUE)[[1]]
#[1] "abc"                    "xyz" 
#[3] "poi (cv, r2, 44, rghj)" "wer"
```

Comment: Thnx Arun. Do you know where i could read up on (*SKIP)(*FAIL)? Have never seen them

Comment: @dimitris_ps  You can read more about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex)