# How to remove all characters not inside parentheses using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a string that contains commas both inside and outside of a parentheses block:
    `foo(bat,foo),bat`

How can I use regex to replace the comma not inside parentheses?
                                                                  `foo(bat,foo)bat`

Comment: what if blocks are nested?

Comment: Split the string by the parentheses, replace the pieces that are outside, recombine the pieces.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648537/how-to-split-a-string-by-commas-positioned-outside-of-parenthesis. Hope it helps.

Comment: Is the comma is inside a nested parentheses, don't remove it. `foo(ba(t,f)oo),bat` becomes `foo(ba(t,f)oo)bat`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that there are no nested parentheses and there are no invalid pairings of parentheses, you can do this with a regex based on the fact that a comma will only be outside a pair of parentheses **if and only if there are an even number of `(` and `)` symbols that follow it**. Thus, you can use a lookahead regex to achieve this.

```
,(?![^(]*\))
```

If there are nested parentheses, it becomes a context-free grammar and you cannot capture this with a regular expression alone. You are better off just using split methods.

example:

```
import re
ori_str = "foo(bat,foo),bat  foo(bat,foo),bat";
rep_str = re.sub(r',(?![^(]*\))', '', ori_str)
print(rep_str)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really want to use `re`, or is anyway to achieve your goal is ok?

In the latter case, here is a way to do it:

```
mystring = 'foo(bat,foo),bat'
''.join(si + ',' if '(' in si else si for si in mystring.split(','))

#'foo(bat,foo)bat'
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering that we want to remove all commas outside of all blocks and don't want to modify nested blocks.

Let's add string validation for cases when there are unclosed/unopened blocks found with

```
def validate_string(string):
    left_parts_count = len(string.split('('))
    right_parts_count = len(string.split(')'))
    diff = left_parts_count - right_parts_count
    if diff == 0:
        return
    if diff < 0:
        raise ValueError('Invalid string: "{string}". '
                         'Number of closed '
                         'but not opened blocks: {diff}.'
                         .format(string=string,
                                 diff=-diff))
    raise ValueError('Invalid string: "{string}". '
                     'Number of opened '
                     'but not closed blocks: {diff}.'
                     .format(string=string,
                             diff=diff))
```

then we can do our job without regular expressions, just using `str` methods

```
def remove_commas_outside_of_parentheses(string):
    # if you don't need string validation
    # then remove this line and string validator
    validate_string(string)

    left_parts = string.split('(')
    if len(left_parts) == 1:
        # no opened blocks found,
        # remove all commas
        return string.replace(',', '')

    left_outer_part = left_parts[0]

    left_outer_part = left_outer_part.replace(',', '')

    left_unopened_parts = left_parts[-1].split(')')
    right_outer_part = left_unopened_parts[-1]
    right_outer_part = right_outer_part.replace(',', '')
    return '('.join([left_outer_part] +
                    left_parts[1:-1] +
                    [')'.join(left_unopened_parts[:-1]
                              + [right_outer_part])])
```

it can look a bit nasty, i suppose, but it works.

## Tests

```
>>>remove_commas_outside_of_parentheses('foo,bat')
foobat
>>>remove_commas_outside_of_parentheses('foo,(bat,foo),bat')
foo(bat,foo)bat
>>>remove_commas_outside_of_parentheses('bar,baz(foo,(bat,foo),bat),bar,baz')
barbaz(foo,(bat,foo),bat)barbaz
```

"broken" ones:

```
>>>remove_commas_outside_of_parentheses('(')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 4, in remove_commas_outside_of_parentheses
  File "<input>", line 17, in validate_string
ValueError: Invalid string: "(". Number of opened but not closed blocks: 1.
>>>remove_commas_outside_of_parentheses(')')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 4, in remove_commas_outside_of_parentheses
  File "<input>", line 12, in validate_string
ValueError: Invalid string: ")". Number of closed but not opened blocks: 1.
```

Comment: Fails for `foo,(bat,foo),bat` and for `foo(bat,foo)bar,bat`.

Comment: This only works in the cases `,(` and `),` but not when commas are elsewhere, `,foo(bat,foo)`

Comment: @BinhPhan: should we remove commas when there is no blocks at all?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov Thanks, the string validation was an interesting implementation!

Comment: If there are no blocks, then remove all commas