# How to split a string by dashes outside of square brackets

Tags: r, regex

I would like to split strings like the following:

```
x <- "abc-1230-xyz-[def-ghu-jkl---]-[adsasa7asda12]-s-[klas-bst-asdas foo]"
```

by dash (`-`) on the condition that those dashes must not be contained inside a pair of `[]`. The expected result would be

```
c("abc", "1230", "xyz", "[def-ghu-jkl---]", "[adsasa7asda12]", "s",
     "[klas-bst-asdas foo]")
```

Notes:

- There is no nesting of square brackets inside each other.
- The square brackets can contain any characters / numbers / symbols except square brackets.
- The other parts of the string are also variable so that we can only assume that we split by `-` whenever it's not inside `[]`.

There's a similar question for python ([How to split a string by commas positioned outside of parenthesis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648537)) but I haven't yet been able to accurately adjust that to my scenario.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use look ahead to verify that there is no `]` following sooner than a `[`:

[`-(?![^[]*\])`](https://regex101.com/r/x0WbVt/2)

So in R:

```
strsplit(x, "-(?![^[]*\\])", perl=TRUE)
```

#### Explanation:

- `-`: match the hyphen
- `(?!    )`: negative look ahead: if that part is found after the previously matched hyphen, it invalidates the match of the hyphen.

  - `[^[]`: match any character that is not a `[`
  - `*`: match any number of the previous
  - `\]`: match a literal `]`. If this matches, it means we found a `]` before finding a `[`. As all this happens in a negative look ahead, a match here means the hyphen  is *not* a match. Note that a `]` is a special character in regular expressions, so it must be escaped with a backslash (although it *does* work without escape, as the engine knows there is no matching `[` preceding it -- but I prefer to be clear about it being a literal). And as backslashes have a special meaning in string literals (they also denote an escape), that backslash itself must be escaped again in this string, so it appears as `\\]`.

Comment: So simple ! But I don't understand everything. Could you please give some explanations for `[^[]*\\]`. It seems for axemple that `-(?![^[]*])` works as well. What are the `\\\` for ?

Comment: Added an explanation.

Comment: Very instructive. Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

Instead of splitting, extract the parts:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(x, "(\\[[^\\[]*\\]|[^-])+")
```

Comment: That's what I was going for, but you beat me to it ;) [Live ideone sample](https://ideone.com/z8txYx).

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with `r` language, but I believe it can do regex based search and replace. Instead of struggling with one single regex split function, I would go in 3 steps:

- replace `-` in all `[....]` parts by a invisible char, like `\x99`
- split by `-`
- for each element in the above split result(array/list), replace `\x99` back to `-`

For the first step, you can find the parts by `\[[^]]`

Comment: This is generally also an acceptable approach but I prefer a more direct way as demonstrated in some of the other answers